# Set statement, return empty string if error

Tags: vb.net

From the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) there is an example at the bottom of the page which I have recreated in vb.net.

Before the following function runs, I save some data from a textfile into a dictionary called T.

For example:

Name - *T0962*

Value - *5.89*

```
Public Shared Function initialization()

    'Variables initialization
    Dim parts As New List(Of Intialization)

    'Add parts to the list.
    parts.Add(New Intialization() With {
         .PartName = "T0962",
         .PartId = T.Item(.PartName))
    })

    If parts.Exists(Function(p) p.PartName = "T0962") Then
            Dim value = parts.Where(Function(p) p.PartName = variable_type).FirstOrDefault()
            Msgbox(value.PartId)
    End If

End Function
```

The program works perfectly when I have *"T0962"* variable. When that variable does not exist in the textfile, it does not exist in the dictionary aswell. Thus, I get an error in the code, because the .PartId fails to be initialized. This is because in that textfile sometimes I have that value sometimes I do not.

After I have analized carefully I have noticed that the error happens in the Property statement, at *Set(value As String)* to be more exactly.

```
Public Property PartId() As String
    Get
        Return m_PartId
    End Get
'here the error happens
    Set(value As String)
        m_PartId = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Is there a way to avoid this in the Set statement? For example when there is an error then return an empty string?

Please let me know if there is something you do not understand.

Comment: What's this `T.Item(.PartName))` Here which PartName you have referred to ?This is the problem

Comment: What does `T.Item(.PartName)` equal if the variable doesn't exist? You could do something like `.PartId = If(T.Item(.PartName) = Nothing, "", T.Item(.PartName))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Try Below. It works for me.

```
Dim partName As String

partName = "T0962"
parts.Add(New Intialization() With {
     .PartName = partName,
     .PartId = T.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.Key = partName).Value
    })
```

Comment: I have tried it before but without success. Seems like the error happens right in the first line of Set (value As String). Doesn't even go in Try.

Comment: @RobertKodra, added another piece of code in my answer. Probably it will fix your problem.

Comment: It's kinda the same thing as before. Still the error persist. Somehow there should be a way to return an empty string when the value is not added to the dictionary.

Comment: @RobertKodra, It should work now. See my updated answer.